# Unable to turn email forwarding off with /etc/aliases file

Tags: email, exim, aliases

I was testing forwarding to an external account with this in `/etc/aliases`:

`some_user: some_user,me@example.com`

The email was going to the external address but not to the internal. So I removed the entry from `/etc/aliases` to try to get things back to normal and did `sudo newaliases` and restarted exim. I do not have postfix or anything else installed except exim.

But even after doing this, email continues to flow only to the `me@example.com` account. What do I have to do get the system to forget the external forwarding address?

**UPDATE** I stopped the exim daemon and emails are still going out. So I really don't have any idea what is sending them. I thought it was exim. These emails are getting triggered by a cron job. Maybe I need to restart the cron daemon.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a misconfiguration.

Comment: It's okay to have misconfigurations. I've written a few myself.

Answer (score 0):

OK, forgot I had put a MAILTO in the cron file as part of an earlier experiment.